# increase default limit of sales_order pagination

Tags: adminhtml, sales-order, pagination

<strike>How can I achieve in the sales_order adminhtml to display the pagination additionally below the grid?</strike>

Also, I would like to have a default limit of 50 rows instead of 20 (in the sales_order pagination). Is that <strike>also</strike> possible?

EDIT: Since it was a bad idea to combine two questions, I opened a new one for the unsolved question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96158/add-another-pagination-below-sales-order-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possiable,You can do this  by changing the value of a variable.

Magento is set **the default pagination value at 20 by using variable**
[*`$_defaultLimit`*](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php#L72) .

As per as you requirement ,you **need change this variable value at 50**.So you **should rewrite class** [*`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`*](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php#L34) and st this variable  value at 50.

**rewrite xml code:**

```
<blocks>
   <adminhtml>
     <rewrite>
      <sales_order_grid>Amit_CustomSales_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
     </rewrite>
   </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

### Rewrite class :

```
<?php
class Amit_CustomSales_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{
    protected $_defaultLimit    = 50;
}
```

Comment: thanks works! Any idea for my second problem to show a second pagination at the bottom of the grid?